# angularjs ng-pattern not working for textarea

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a textarea that needs to be validated. If the textarea is not valid, then a button should be disabled. I am trying to use ngPattern to validate that textarea, but it doesn't seem to be working. My example code is as follows:

```
<div ng-app="test">
<form name="theForm" ng-controller="FormCtrl" novalidate="novalidate" autocomplete="off">
    <textarea ng-pattern="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b, \d{1,5}, (external|internal)"></textarea>
    <button ng-disabled="theForm.$invalid" ng-click="action()">Action</button>
</form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sYyf2/7/

The pattern in the box should be "(IP address), (port), (internal|external)" where (port) is a number between 1 and 5 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the forward slash `/` to wrap up the expression like this

```
ng-pattern="/ ..you regexp.. /"
```

Comment: And also add a ng-model attribute to the textarea.